# Python Pandas: How to sum up columns that also include missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, missing-data

I have a df with several columns by three of them are like this:

```
num1  num2   num3 
1      NaN    1
NaN     1     1
1       1     1
```

and I would like to create another column "sum_num" and add the values in per row for all the columns (alternative would be to count number of ones cause the values are all ones).

Expected outcome:

```
num1  num2   num3 sum_num
1      NaN    1      2
NaN     1     1      2
1       1     1      3
```

Now I have tried this code but what I am having in the "sum_num" columns in only NaNs.

```
df['sum_num'] = df.num1 + df.num2 + df.num3
```

Does anybody know how to ignore missing values and still either sum the ones or count them to get the desired outcome per row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` on `axis=1`

```
In [202]: df['sum_num'] = df.sum(axis=1)

In [203]: df
Out[203]:
   num1  num2  num3  sum_num
0     1   NaN     1        2
1   NaN     1     1        2
2     1     1     1        3
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the dataframe has some other columns and I only want these specific columns to be summed up?

Comment: `df[list_of_columns].sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: yes I have figured that out Thanks. Would  you also tell me how can I count the number of ones instead of summing them up?

Comment: `df.count(axis=1)` :-) ?

Comment: haha thanks I feel stupid now, I meant more if not all the values are one, for instance if I also have zeros. How can I count both ones and zeros

Answer (score 1):

In practice you can create a subset form a dataframe, here `df`:

```
sum_num = df[['num1', 'num2', 'num3']]
```

then add the subset to `df`:

```
df['summed'] = sum_num.sum(axis=1)
```