# Summing pandas columns containing Nan's (missing values)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, nan, missing-data

I'm following up on questions that were asked a few years ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235318/python-pandas-how-to-sum-up-columns-that-also-include-missing-values) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056567/how-to-sum-with-missing-values-in-pandas)

I would like to sum two columns from a pandas data frame where both columns contain missing values.
I have scrolled the internet, but coudn't find this precise output I'm looking for.

**I have a df as follows**, and I want to sum col1 and col2

```
col1   col2 
1       NaN      
NaN      1       
1        1     
Nan     Nan
```

**The output I want:**

```
col1   col2    col_sum
1       NaN       1
NaN      1        1
1        1        2
Nan     Nan      Nan
```

**What I don't want:**

When simply using `df['col_sum'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']` gives me

```
col1   col2    col_sum
1       NaN      Nan
NaN      1       Nan
1        1        2
Nan     Nan      Nan
```

When using the `sum()` function as suggested in the above (linked) threads gives me

```
col1   col2    col_sum
1       NaN       1
NaN      1        1
1        1        2
Nan     Nan       0
```

Hence, I would like that the sum of a number with a missing value outputs that number, and the sum of two missing values outputs a missing value.
Treating Nan's as 0 values is a problem for me. Because later on, if I'm taking the `mean()` of `col_sum` having a `0` or a `Nan` will give a totally different result (or isn't it ??).

Comment: The solution in [`the link given`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056663/12833166) by you should work fine. Check `df['col1'].add(df['col2'], fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) with `fill_value` parameter:

```
df['col_sum'] = df['col1'].add(df['col2'], fill_value=0)
```

Or `sum` with `min_count=1` parameter:

```
df['col_sum'] = df.sum(min_count=1, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
0   1.0   NaN      1.0
1   NaN   1.0      1.0
2   1.0   1.0      2.0
3   NaN   NaN      NaN
```